# Have multiple ComboBox's use the same event

Tags: vb.net, events, combobox, event-handling

I have roughly 140 ComboBox on a form. When some selects a new item within one of the box's I would like to highlight that box.

I would like to use the SelectionChangeCommitted event and I would use the following code:

```
Private Sub cmbDesk1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbDesk1.SelectionChangeCommitted
 Dim tbControl As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
 tbControl.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
 tabFloor1.Focus()
```

I know that I can add extra lines after the "Handles" section of the subroutine declaration but it there a neat way of doing it without adding every ComboBox to it?
Something similar to

```
Me.TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
```

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: It's not the same event.  It's the same event handler.  `SelectionChangeCommitted` is the event and `cmbDesk1_SelectionChangeCommitted` is a method that handles that event.

Comment: I would tend to stick with the `Handles` clause.  You can still have the IDE do it for you.  You simply select all the controls in the designer, open the Properties window, click the Events button and then double-click the event.  That will generate a method and add all the controls to the `Handles` clause.  You can also use the drop-down for an event to select an existing method.

Answer (score 4):

You can always loop all combobox and [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) yourself.

```
For Each cb As ComboBox In Me.TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
    AddHandler cb.SelectionChangeCommitted, AddressOf cmbDesk1_SelectionChangeCommitted
Next
```

This should be done once.

Comment: I assume this would be done somewhere on the form load event and gives it the handler at run time?

Comment: @MattBartlett yes. You would do it before you need it.

Comment: Works a charm, thanks very much. With 140 Combox's being programmed to act exactly the same this new piece of coding knowledge is going be very very handy.

Comment: It's probably not as necessary in this specific instance, but it's often a good idea to pair `AddHandler` with a corresponding `RemoveHandler`.  I'd also strongly recommend using `Option Strict` (if you aren't already doing so), as you can get some nasty and subtle bugs when the signature of your handler doesn't exactly match the event signature.